# How to terminate at if and start over for loop

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a situation like this

```
for url in ArrayOfUrls:
  driver.get(url)
  try:
     elem1 =driver.find_element_by_xpath("xpath")
     elem1.click()
  except:
     print("elem1 not found") 
  try: 
     elem2 =driver.find_element_by_xpath("xpath")
     elem2.click()     

     Error = driver.find_element_by_xpath("xpath")         
     if Error:             
        break 
  except: 
       print("elem2 not found")
```

At this point I want to break execution in If statment and want driver to launch 2nd url being in for loop from the array, is that  possible, please help. Right now i get error "break out loop", please tell me what can be the alternate approach to achieve the purpose

Comment: Expert call please

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer: I don't know python so this will be a more pseudo-code answer*

You'll need to flags to skip over code instead of break.

So your code will look something like this:

```
for url in ArrayOfUrls {
    set error_flag = false;

    if (test1 && !error_flag) {
        // Do stuff
        // On error set error_flag = true
    }

    if (test2 && !error_flag) {
        // Do stuff
        // On error set error_flag = true
    }

    if (test3 && !error_flag) {
        // Do stuff
        // On error set error_flag = true
    }
}
```

Basically, set a flag at the beginning of each loop to false to signify no errors. From there on, all actions should test the value of the flag. If it is "not false" (therefore true) then the code knows there has been an error and needs to skip over everything until the next loop.

It's not pretty, but works well in small doses. Technically, you don't need to check the flag on the very first action, but I do because:

1. Code is visually clean/aligned
2. If you need to move things around, it's already wrapped in the if() statement